# VBA. Comparing jagged arrays results in "Type Mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with this snippet of code which should be elemental. I was wondering if someone could give me a hand. Any ideas would be very much appreciated, I'm pretty new in VBA.

My code is:

```
    Dim table() as Variant: table = Array(Array(0,0,0))
    Dim aux() as Variant: aux = Array(0,0,0)
    If table(0) = aux then
    End If
```

The code doesn't even execute, Excel throws a mismatch exception in the If line. I have "paraphrased" the code in every way possible and haven't been successful on getting it to work (of course the code is not as simple as this one, but this one that does nothing doesn't execute either...)

Thanks in advance for your time,

Comment: You can't directly compare two arrays for equality

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare two 1-dimensional arrays for equality as indicated by your provided sample code, then you'll need to use the Join function, like so:

```
Sub tst()

    Dim table() As Variant: table = Array(Array(0, 0, 0))
    Dim aux() As Variant:   aux = Array(0, 0, 0)

    If Join(table(0), ",") = Join(aux, ",") Then
        MsgBox "The same"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not the same"
    End If

End Sub
```

As a note, make sure the Join delimiter being used will not be in any of the elements of either array being tested against.  John Coleman brought up a great point that this could give a false positive against an array of `(0, "0,0")` when using a comma delimiter as shown in the provided answer.

Comment: What if `aux = Array(0, "0,0")` ?

Comment: In general, whoever is coding this should know the contents of the array.  In a case like `Array(0, "0,0")`, it would be easy enough to change the Join delimiter to something that is known to not be in any of the elements.

Comment: I was being a bit pedantic. For most uses this is perfectly fine (so +1) but if OP wants to do this with arrays of strings (a natural use-case for jagged arrays where each array might come from applying `Split()` to different lines of text) they should be aware of the dangers of false positives.

Comment: It's a really good point to bring up, the user should be aware of those potential pitfalls.  I should have mentioned it in my answer :)

Comment: The pipe character | is my go-to delimiter